# Counter in file name

Tags: php, loops, laravel, filenames, laravel-5.1

So the problem is: whenever a user uploads a file, it is being checked if the file exists in the directory. If exists, in the filename should be put _n as suffix where n is a number. So with the second upload, the filename should look like file_2.extension  Should this be done with some kind of loop?

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $user = Auth::id();
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $onlyname = basename($filename, $extension);
        $filePath = 'uploads\\'.$user.'\\'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            if($file->move('uploads\\'.$user, $onlyname.'_'.$counter.'.'.$extension)){                
                $uploadHandler = new UploadHandler();       
                $uploadAttributes = $uploadHandler->uploadAttributes($request);   
            }
        }                     
    }
```

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want, but if you don't care about the file names as long as they are unique you can also use: `uniqid().'.'.$extension;`

Comment: Nope, I need the original file name

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need a `while` loop

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $user = Auth::id();
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $onlyname = basename($filename, $extension);
    $filePath = 'uploads\\'.$user.'\\'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $counter = 2;
        while (file_exists($filePath)){
            $filePath = 'uploads\\'.$user. $onlyname.'_'.$counter.'.'.$extension;
            $counter ++;
        }
    }
    if($file->move($filePath)){                
        $uploadHandler = new UploadHandler();       
        $uploadAttributes = $uploadHandler->uploadAttributes($request);   
    }                     
}
```

Comment: the counter should start at 2 based on OP's requirement

Comment: @khuderm true. A detail but ok ;) updated the answer.

Comment: There is something wrong with the $filePath variable

Comment: @alex, sorry typo it had a comma which should be a dot. Try again

Comment: it gives me an error that the file cannot be moved to the directory

Comment: @alex does the dir has write access? Echo what the path is, most file systems use / instead of \ (linux vs windows) so you might want to try / instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use while-loop, like this:

```
while( file_exists($filePath) ) {
     // increment your $counter and update $filePath accordingly
}
```